# Is it possible to do conditional statements in the CssClass property?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using a repeater control. One of my item attributes is a boolean. I know I can do a conditional statement in the Text property, such as:

```
Text='<%# Item.Boolean ? "Text 1" : "Text 2" %>
```

However, what if I want the same text but a different CSS style depending on the boolean?

Is code like the following possible?

```
CssClass=<%# Item.Boolean ? "CssClass1" : "CssClass2" %>
```

Comment: I'm not at work so I can't access visual studio right now. I'm just curious.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. In that case: yes it should work, it's just another `String` property - although you'll probably need to use the same enclosing single quotes as in your `Text` example.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it like that.  is not a runat server type of tag, so it cannot attempt to execute the logic there.  Instead, you need to set the properties for the gridview in Page_PreRenderComplete.

Use something like the following to do it:

```
protected void Page_PreRenderComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.FormatGridviewRows();
}

private void FormatGridviewRows()
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in this.GridView1.Rows)
    {
        // Don't attempt changes on header / select / etc. Only Datarow
        if (row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow) continue;

        // At least make sure everything has the default class
        row.CssClass = "gridViewRow";

        // Don't affect the first row
        if (row.DataItemIndex <= 0) continue; 

        if (row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Normal || row.RowState == (DataControlRowState.Normal ^ DataControlRowState.Edit))
        {
            row.CssClass = !this.cbForceOverride.Checked 
                ? "gridViewRow" 
                : "gridViewRow gridViewRowDisabled";
        }

        if (row.RowState == DataControlRowState.Alternate || row.RowState == (DataControlRowState.Alternate ^ DataControlRowState.Edit))
        {
            row.CssClass = !this.cbForceOverride.Checked
                ? "gridViewAltRow"
                : "gridViewAltRow gridViewAltRowDisabled";
        }
    }

}
```

and then in your stylesheet:

```
.gridViewRow {
    background-color: #f2f2f2; 
}

.gridViewAltRow {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.gridViewRow, .gridViewAltRow {
    color: #000000;
}

.gridViewRowDisabled, .gridViewAltRowDisabled {
    color: #DDDDDD;
}
```